# tail multiple files and grep the output

Tags: unix, grep, tail

I would like to grep a pattern from multiple log files which are being constantly updated by  some processes and tail the output of this grep continuosly. 
Below command doesnt work and I get

> - tail: warning: following standard input indefinitely is ineffective

```
tail -f  | grep --line-buffered "Search this: " /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log
```

Can someone help sort this out?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/59471/simple-use-of-tail-grep-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should have a look at [`multitail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail) tool (Install using `sudo apt-get install multitail`)

In short, with multitail, you need to use the `--mergeall` flag for viewing output of all in one place

```
multitail --mergeall /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log  | grep --line-buffered "Search this: "
```

You can do the same without using grep

```
multitail -E "Search this: " --mergeall /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log
```

To view the output individually using  multitail, *this will give the filename as well*.

```
multitail -E "Search this: " /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log
```

Comment: What version of multitail are you using? I am unable to grep the output of multitail with the version packaged with Debian: _multitail 5.2.13_

Comment: @Thor Corrected my answer.

Comment: @mu無 Once you're finished, how do you get rid of the bar underneath your terminal? I did Ctrl+C and it exited the multitail, but that bar is still there. Not even logging out of the server helped. I had to completely close my terminal. Annoying!!!

Comment: @IRGeekSauce Don't have access to a linux machine right now, so can't check. You can try asking a new question on the site for help from community :)

Comment: @mu無 I figured it out. Just type "clear".

Answer (score 11):

the mistake is that you give the files to the grep command and not the tail.

the tail -f needs to get the files as input. try:

```
tail -f  /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log | grep --line-buffered "Search this: "
```

to get also the file names (however it will not be like grep output it is):

```
tail /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log | grep --line-buffered -e'^==> .* <==$' -e'Search this: '
```

Comment: thanks. This works partially but I dont get the filenames where the pattern is found?

Comment: solution: `for f in path/to/files*.txt; do echo $f; tail $f | grep 'SEARCH-THIS';  done;`

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and the simple answer should be: *Use the prefix switch with tail*, but unfortunately this is currently not implemented in most versions of `tail`.

As I see it, you have two options: adapt the standard tools to the task (see [*Udys* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089306/1331399)) or write your own tool with your favorite scripting/programming language.

Below is one way you could do it with the `File::Tail::Multi` module for `perl`. Note that you may need to install the module from CPAN (`cpan -i File::Tail::Multi`).

Save the following script e.g. `mtail` to your executable path and make the script executable.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Tail::Multi;

$| = 1;  # Enable autoflush

$tail = File::Tail::Multi->new(RemoveDuplicate => 0,
                               OutputPrefix    => 'f',
                               Files           => \@ARGV);

while(1) { $tail->read; $tail->print; sleep 2 }
```

Change `OutputPrefix` to `'p'` if you prefer full path prefixes.

Run it like this:

```
mtail /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log | grep --line-buffered "Search this: "
```

You do not need to specify `--line-buffered` when `grep` is the last command, so this is sufficient:

```
mtail /var/links/proc2/id/myprocess*/Daily/myprocess*.log | grep "Search this: "
```

Comment: 1) How is this different from using multitail? 2) Will it output by filenames, as OP asks in comments to @Udys answer>

Comment: @ansh0l: 1) multitail outputs its results in curses, which is not greppable. 2) Yes, each line has the originating file name prefixed.

Comment: Ah ok, +1 for curses. But with -E flag of multitail, you won't need to do the grep itself.